# Primefaces input text inside select many menu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to make a selectManyMenu with spinner or input text inside, to be able to get the following result:
[image]

Here after my code:

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="opt-list" value="#{myBean.selectedOptionList}"
                converter="optConverter" filter="true"
                filterMatchMode="contains" showCheckbox="true"
                var="selectedOpt">

    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.optionList}" var="opt" itemLabel="#{opt.name}" itemValue="#{opt}" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{selectedOpt.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <p:spinner value="#{selectedOpt.nb}" size="1" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

The idea is that the user should be able to select an option and specify a number.
but during execution, i get the following warning/error:

```
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] .....\.....\my-page.xhtml @65,84 value="#{selectedOpt.nb}": JBWEB006016: Target Unreachable, identifier ''selectedOpt'' resolved to null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: ....\......\my-page.xhtml @65,84 value="#{selectedOpt.nb}": JBWEB006016: Target Unreachable, identifier ''selectedOpt'' resolved to null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your "label" problems by replacing `<f:selectItem>`'s itemValue by `#{selectedOpt}` instead of `#{opt}`

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="opt-list" value="#{myBean.selectedOptionList}"
            converter="optConverter" filter="true"
            filterMatchMode="contains" showCheckbox="true"
            var="selectedOpt">

<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.optionList}" var="opt" itemLabel="#{opt.name}" itemValue="#{selectedOpt}" />
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{selectedOpt.name}" />
</p:column>

<p:column>
    <p:spinner value="#{selectedOpt.nb}" size="1" />
</p:column>
```

Keep in mind that will not solve your spinner problem. See : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16964

Comment: Is it not allowed to use nested components? Input text inside selectManyMenu for instance.